# How can I see the items which settled in drill behaviour in View Tabular Data?

Tags: cognos, cognos-8, cognos-tm1

I have a chart.
And I allow Drill up and Drill down option.
I have a filter that it effect my chart.
When I want to view tabular data with setting my parameter , I dont see which I want.Its just show data items like dont effect paramater.It s dont filter problem.

When I run report and click markers on the chart , drill down works and look true but when the value promt change everythings look normal but the conditional style is wrong. I think and belive the main problem is drill down option.

(
for example : I have two columns. region and topregion.
If I look view tabular data without setting parameter , the result is :

region              topregion
--------          ------------ 
a                                 X
b                                 X
c                                  X

And when I look view tabular data with setting parameter(topregion = ?p1?)--p1:a

region              topregion
--------              ------------
a                                  X
b                                 X
c                                 X

but you know it dont like that.
I want to see it like this :

region          topregion
--------           ------------
k                                  a
l                                    a
m                             a

but it dont.

How can i fix this?

thanks...

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a calculated column. If the value of p1 is empty, you pass the orginal top region. If it is not, you replace with a the region you have selected.